# Is it possible to execute some code when visual studio enters break mode?

Tags: debugging, exception, break, mode

I have a large proces that I need to debug and the proces could stop at anytime. I have configured Visual Studio 2017, to stop at any thrown exception, as in, even if it is handled, because I want to see what caused the exception. What I need is some sort of alarm when this happens, so that I can leave the program to run and then alert me if anything comes up. The only thing I have found is an alarm sound when a break point is hit, but it might not be a break point and I need more than a sound, I need to be able to execute some code, so that I can make my Phone go nuts or whatever. Is there any way I can trigger code when the debugger enters break mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is, using a VS package. You'll need to add this attribute on top of the class in order for code to run on package startup:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)] ///Able to run code on solution startup
```

Add these class values variables:

```
private DTE2 applicationObject;
private BuildEvents buildEvents;
private DebuggerEvents debugEvents;
```

then the following code can run:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
            base.Initialize();

            applicationObject = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));
            buildEvents = applicationObject.Events.BuildEvents;
            debugEvents = applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents;

            SetupEventHandlers();
        }
```

And finally the code we have "all" being waiting for:

```
private void SetupEventHandlers()
        {
            //buildEvents.OnBuildDone += (scope, action) =>
            //{

            //};

            debugEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += delegate (dbgEventReason reason, ref dbgExecutionAction action)
            {

            };

            //var componentModel =
            //    GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel;
            //if (componentModel == null)
            //{
            //    Debug.WriteLine("componentModel is null");
            //    return;
            //}
            //var operationState = componentModel.GetService<IOperationState>();
            //operationState.StateChanged += OperationStateOnStateChanged;
        }
```